# ZeroMQ : getting Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.zeromq.ZMQException: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state(0x9523dfb) on retry

Tags: java, zeromq

i have this senario :
client that try to send to server , but the server is offline . 
the socket.send(request, 0); in inside java Timer thread :

this is the thread run()
the ZMQ.Socket m_socket is initiates outside the thread

```
public void run() {

  m_socket.send(request, 0);
 byte[] reply = m_socket.recv(0);
 //get seperator
 byte[] empty1 = m_socket.recv(0);
 //get secound frame
  byte[] byteFileStruct = m_socket.recv(0);  
  if(null!=reply)  // this is indication that the server is offline , is there better way to check ? 
  {
    ......
  }

}
```

now the Timer triggers the run() methods again and when it execute the  m_socket.send(request, 0); in the second round im getting :

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.zeromq.ZMQException: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state(0x9523dfb)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.send(Native Method)
    at com.agent.core.Poller$PollarWorker.run(Poller.java:155)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

do i need to create new socket each round ?
that is this :

```
 m_context = ZMQ.context(1);
        m_socket = m_context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
        m_socket.setReceiveTimeOut(2000);
        m_socket.setSendTimeOut(2000);
        m_socket.connect (sControllerDomain);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the code, but it looks like you're creating the socket on one thread, and using it on another one.

ZeroMQ socket **must** be used on the thread where it has been created. On the other hand, one ZeroMQ context is **usually** enough for an application.

Working with ZeroMQ sockets is much more convenient in message loops: socket is created before loop and destroyed right after it. Really, there's no need for timers/monitors/etc., ZeroMQ itself provides synchronisation primitives.

I'd recommend to review these chapters in ZeroMQ guide:

> [Multithreading with ØMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc45)
>
> [Chapter 3 - Advanced Request-Reply Patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc52)

Comment: yeah but i need to have some function that will check each N sec for server if he online . 
how can i do it with out some timer ?

Comment: @user63898 There might be different solutions depending on the problem being solved. For example, if you need to monitor state of the server, it's much better to create PUB socket on server and generate heartbeat. The client becomes simple subscriber that waits for heartbeat in a loop. If no message has beed received in specified time interval, the server is likely to be down.